# get mac address of device

Tags: command-line, networking, virtualization

I have a scientific instrument, which I am trying to connect via cross over cable. I need to get that device's mac address so that I can configure the communications server.

How can I get the MAC Address of the device connected via a crossover cable?

Comment: Tried `arp-scan`?

Comment: I'll try it. I tried "arp" and nothing came back. its been about 10 years since I last did this type of networking.

Comment: have you already looked [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/176405/how-to-discover-the-mac-address-of-machines-in-a-network)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `nmap`.

If you don't know the exact IP-address:

```
sudo nmap -sP 192.168.1.0/24
```

This will scan your entire network. Change *192.168.1.0/24* with your network and CIDR.

You can also specify a IP-address:

```
sudo nmap -sP 192.168.1.50
```

Comment: im not sure that it has and IP yet.  This is a bootp server. or it will be.

Comment: -1 And where is the MAC address?

Comment: @A.B. You have to you use sudo or doing it as root. If not you'll only get the IP-address.

Comment: Then write "sudo".

Comment: @A.B. Yeah my bad. Sorry I didn't mentioned that.

Comment: thx, downvote removed